# migrate from sharepoint 2007 too Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, migration, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2013

We have different business divisions and each division has its ecommerce site hosted as webpart in SharePoint 2007. We also have product/adv images/documents in SharePoint.

We want to migrate from SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint 2013 and as per our initial research we noted that we must first migrate to SharePoint 2010 and then to SharePoint 2013

Questions :

1. what is the best way to migrate from sharepoint 2007 to sharepoint 2013 considering above context. please provide pointers..
2. or should we re-write our webpart code in mvc and get rid of SharePoint. since we have soa arch i belive it would not be big pain to do so.. just ui webparts will be replace with mvc site
3. which third party migration tools can be used considering their reliability and cost.

please suggest best way to go ahead.

Comment: our current system has different webpart dlls for each ui module which make service calls and set/get data. in 80% of system we don't use sharepoint we use sharepoint api to deploy pages in sharepoint and to read image list from sharepoint for our slideshow on home page. + we have admin section where user can upload product image/pdf in sharepoint..  thats it ... rest of the code can be thought of .net ui dlls deployed in sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, there's not direct migration path from 2007 to 2013. It's hard to give a definitive answer without knowing more about your environment, it really comes down to trying to estimate the cost and time doing a manual migration (2007-->2010-->) versus purchasing a tool.

I have one customer that used Metalogix to go from 2007 to 2013 and it was fairly successful. They had a couple of branding issues and some code that had to be re-written to use updated API's but considering the scope of the migration, it was fairly smooth.

Ditching SharePoint and re-writing everything using MVC.... Not sure about that one. Even though you have a SOA architecture in place, it doesn't mean it will replace everything that SharePoint provides. It does a lot of things; security, service app scalability, branding, ECM, BCS, search, etc.

Answer (score 0):

UI issue may be faced as below

1. Migration HTML content (in content webpart) from ntext data type to XML data.
2. SharePoint adds some extra tags for xml validation and it distorts to whole UI for all the pages. Means look and feel will not be as it is after migration.
3. Table based old structure in menus and drop-dwon is very hard to manage. It must be in  and Box model for better UI management.

Answer (score 0):

I had used Metalogix in my migration projects and it worked 70% fine, however be ready for the post deployment fixes as you might have to rewrite some scripts. But overall it works fairly good. I would also suggest you to run a report before migration using SPCAF tool.

Comment: Instead of a new answer, try commenting under the question. This is not a new answer.